# Multithread way to download images and write them as blobs to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, python-requests, blob, pyodbc

I have a Python script that downloads images (more truthfully it uses [Splash render.png](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#render-png) to take a screenshot of a given URL, but that is irrelevant to this question) and writes them as blobs to a SQL server db using pyodbc. It works fine, but is rather slow and I'm interested in how I can increase the speed using multithreading.

The requests to download the images are made using python-requests and I'm reasonably confident on how to make these requests in parallel, but as for writing the response contents to db, I'm not sure pyodbc is going to play well with multithreading. What other options do I have?

Maybe Twisted web client and adbapi are the way to go?

Comment: Don't store the images in the database, enable the [FILESTREAM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx) feature and store the images on the filesystem.  You'll have much better performance for both saving and pulling the images.

Comment: Filestream is certainly one option but I disagree with @JohnEisbrener that it will have much better performance. Filestream is best suited when the images are larger than 1MB. It states that quite clearly in the documentation. Sometime storing the image in a varbinary(max) makes more sense. And other times, storing the file to disc and a path (or filename) in the database make the most sense. There is no hard and fast rule here. A lot of it depends on your specific needs.

Comment: I assumed the images are larger than 1MB, hence the request for faster loads, but good clarification just the same @Sean!